# Hive - Renaming Fields With Same Name As A Datatype

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, rename

I have a Hive table like such:

```
CREATE TABLE mytest (name int, timestamp bigint, donation int);
```

I am using Hive 0.12. Note the field "timestamp". Incidentally, Hive 0.12+ introduced a new data type called `timestamp`. Say I want to rename this field to `time_stamp`

I tried these:

1. `ALTER TABLE mytest CHANGE timestamp time_stamp BIGINT;`
2. `ALTER TABLE mytest CHANGE COLUMN timestamp time_stamp BIGINT;`
3. `ALTER TABLE mytest CHANGE [timestamp] time_stamp BIGINT;`
4. `` ALTER TABLE mytest CHANGE `timestamp` time_stamp BIGINT; ``

However, all of them give me the following error:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:38 mismatched input 'CHANGE' expecting KW_EXCHANGE near 'mytest' in alter exchange partition
```

I am dead sure this is because of the fact that my field name is the same as a data type name. How can I alter the schema for `mytest` **without** having to do the following?

```
CREATE mytest_cpy AS SELECT mytest.name, mytest.timestamp AS time_stamp, 
mytest.donation FROM mytest; 

DROP TABLE mytest; 

ALTER TABLE mytest_cpy RENAME TO mytest;
```

Thanks! Any/all help is appreciated!

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue, no clue what might be wrong. In my case the column name isn't a data type actually, so this shouldn't be the underlying reason.

Answer (score 2):

Use backticks for any unusal column names, either containing weird symbols or the same as data types. This works for Hive 0.14:

```
ALTER TABLE mytest CHANGE COLUMN `timestamp` time_stamp BIGINT;
```

Answer (score 0):

in MS SQL use:

```
EXECUTE sp_rename 'dbo.mytest.timestamp', 'time_stamp', 'COLUMN'
```

in MYSQL try:

```
USE database_name;
ALTER TABLE mytest CHANGE timestamp time_stamp BIGINT;
```

or:

```
ALTER TABLE database_name.mytest CHANGE timestamp time_stamp BIGINT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this post have answers but still:

If you try to give column name which is [Reserved Keywords for HIVE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Keywords,Non-reservedKeywordsandReservedKeywords) then error will occur.

For overriding the reserved keywords use can use backtick(`) this is the character below your tilde key or left to 1 key.